# What are both way dielectric polarized mirror

Tags: reflection

I'm looking for a material that would reflect lights on one side but would allow with as little as possible filtering luminous light coming from behind.

Normal both way mirror seems to filter too much light coming from the other side.

Even if I heard about dielectric polarized mirror who offer better performance in reflective and letting lights going through from the other side, I don't understand how it works exactly.

Is someone can explain what is the difference and how it works?  It will help me find a provider and describe my needs.

Comment: A dielectric mirror is a transparent carrier material with a number of thin optical layers on one side. The thickness and optical index of each layer is carefully chosen to filter light for a certain frequency or direction. If you are looking for a general purpose one-way mirror, then, I am afraid, these reciprocal devices won't do the job, either. You could possible get a mirror that would let light in certain directions trough, which would allow for a restricted one-way mirror like effect.

Comment: I think you may want to investigate paired circular polarizers. It won't get you to 100% but is probably the best that can be done.

Comment: Appropriate magneto-optical devices (Faraday rotators) certainly can suppress back-reflection of polarized light. I don't think that is what you are trying to say here though.

Comment: CuriousONe, If I understand well your answer, a normal dielectric mirror would be too transparent to really be used in a practical way as a one way mirror. 

On the other end, you think it could be possible to make a mirror that would let light pass from behind but not coming from the front, making it act as a one way mirror.  In this case, what would be the technic to achieve it?

Comment: Carl Witthoft, i read a little bit about paired polarizers and it seems that it will allow lights in one direction but block the opposite direction.  Giving the effect of 2 way mirror allowing light to come from behind.  Is there any constraint on the transparency of the polarized layer?

Comment: Jon Custer, unfortunately, you lost me, can you elaborate?